# C++ struct array with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'd like to increase age by 1 with function aging(), from struct type data input.

I wanted to get data input as an array of struct, and get struct argument as pointer type, but only to fail (age is not increased)

What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Person
{
    int age;
    double weight, height;
};

void aging(Person* p);

int main()
{
    Person ps[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        cout <<"age :";
        cin >> ps[i].age;
        cout <<"weight :";
        cin >> ps[i].weight;
        cout <<"height :";
        cin >> ps[i].height;
    }

aging(&ps[2]);

for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    cout <<"age after1: "<<ps[i].age<<"weight after1: "<<ps[i].weight<<"height after1:"<<ps[i].height<<"\n";
    }

return 0;
}

void aging(Person* p){
    p-> age++;
}
```

Comment: `What is the problem?` That's what I want to know! Is it a compiler error (if so why didn't you include it?) Is it runtime? (if so, why didn't you describe it?)...

Comment: Age is not increased

Comment: If you ran this under Valgrind, you'd soon see that you're accessing an out-of-range value in `&ps[2]`.  Consider aging `&ps[1]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you called `aging` on an out-of-bounds element of the array `ps`.  You declare `ps` to have two elements, but attempt to access the third element with `ps[2]` (remember, c++ arrays begin at index 0).  If you wanted to call it on the last element of the array, I think you meant to write `aging(&ps[1])`.